# Increasing the speed of For Loop & With statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, indexing, with-statement

I have a code (written below) that works and executes exactly what I need it to do, but I would like to improve it's execution time as sometimes it takes a few seconds for what I believe should only take a split second (if adjusted correctly).

Basically, I am using VBA to do an Index & Match formula with another workbook that it retrieves information (parameters) from. I have comments added to each line to further explain my code (scroll to the right), but I believe the slow processing time has something to do with using my `With statement` for each separate cell inside of the `For loop`. I just want to find a solution to increase the speed of my code as sometimes it takes too long for my application.

Please let me know if you have any questions or suggestions!

```
'This macro uses an Index and Match application to fill in the "Changes Pending Approval" parameters in the "Operator" worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()                                                                   'Occurs after the worksheet is recalculated for the Worksheet object (any changes in the intersect cell)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                                                  'This speeds up the macro by hiding what the macro is doing

If Not Intersect(Range("H4"), Range("H4")) Is Nothing Then                                          'Checking if the "Key" (part or process) has been changed

Dim yChanges As Worksheet, OperatorWs As Worksheet                                                  'Declaring worksheets as variables
Dim yChangesLastRow As Long, Parameters As Long, x As Long, z As Long                               'Declaring variables to count last rows and "x" & "z" as integers (long variables)

Set y = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\Databases\Database_IRR 200-2S.xlsm", Password:="123")            'Sets the Workbook variable as the database filepath
Set yChanges = y.Sheets("Changes")                                                                  'Sets the Worksheet variable as the "Changes" sheet in the database's workbook
Set OperatorWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Operator")                                                'Sets the Worksheet variable as the "Operator" sheet in this workbook
OperatorWs.Unprotect "123"                                                                          'Unprotects the "Operator" sheet

Parameters = yChanges.Range("F1:CL1").Columns.Count                                                 'Counts the number of columns in the "Changes" sheet

yChangesLastRow = yChanges.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                                    'Finds the last row in the "Changes" sheet & counts the number of rows

yChangesLastRow = yChangesLastRow - 2                                                               '-2 from the number of rows to account for the header & Vlookup (2nd) column

z = 6                                                                                               'Sets variable "z" to start with the first parameter in the "Changes" sheet (Column "F")

    For x = 31 To Parameters + 31                                                                   'Sets variable "x" to start from the first Parameter in the "Operator" sheet to the last row
                                                                                                        
        With yChanges                                                                               'With the "Changes" sheet do the following

            Dim IndexRng As Range                                                                   'Declaring variable as a range
            Set IndexRng = .Range(.Cells(3, z), .Cells(yChangesLastRow, z))                         'Sets range variable as the index lookup array (Pending Changes entries)

            Dim MatchRng As Range                                                                   'Declaring variable as a range
            Set MatchRng = .Range("A3:A" & yChangesLastRow)                                         'Sets range variable as the match lookup array (Pending changes "Keys" only)

        End With                                                                                    'Ending the "With statement"

    Dim matchNum As Variant                                                                         'Declaring variable as general datatype
    matchNum = Application.Match(Sheet1.Range("H4").Value, MatchRng, 0)                             'Sets variable equal to the Match function to find the "Key" in the "Changes" sheet

                If Not IsError(matchNum) Then                                                       'Checking if the "Key" is in the "Changes" sheet (True or False)

                    OperatorWs.Range("N" & x).Value = Application.Index(IndexRng, matchNum)         'True: Sets the Changes Pending Approval parameters in the "Operator" sheet

                Else                                                                                'False: no match was found for the "Key" (Part & Process) in the "Changes sheet

                    Exit Sub                                                                        'End the macro

                End If                                                                              'End the "IF" statement
    
    z = z + 1                                                                                       '+1 to execute the "For" statement with the next (lookup) parameter

    Next x                                                                                          'Executes the "For" statement with the next "x" value (+1 until it reaches the "Parameters + 31" integer)

OperatorWs.Protect "123"                                                                            'Protect the "Operator" sheet
    
        y.Save                                                                                      'Save the database Workbook
    
        y.Close False                                                                               'Close the database Workbook

End If                                                                                              'End the "IF" statement

Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                                                   'Must be "True" after running the code to be able to Read/Write the Workbook

End Sub                                                                                             'End the macro
```

Comment: Do not iterate Ranges.  Mass load Variant arrays and iterate those.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but I'm having a difficult time trying to incorporate it. How do I make the switch from iterating my ranges to mass loading variant arrays to iterate? Also to make sure I understand what this accomplishes, I'm updating the values in the array as opposed to updating the values in the cells correct?

Comment: Put comments on their own lines and use less of them. This comment style might be worse than no comments. Most lines don't need an explanation, like the ones that contain the word `End`.

Comment: Your second `With yChanges ` does nothing. There are no dot sourced commands inside that block.

Comment: @HackSlash The reason I have so many lines is for the new intern I am training, to make things clear for him (we will be removing the comments but I agree too many comments can also get confusing). Regarding the second ```With yChanges``` you are correct, I have made the adjustment. I had it do something prior and must have forgotten to remove it, thank you

Comment: @ScottCraner Could you please layout the method to apply variant arrays in my case